# Why does a systemd unit file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` still works for Ubuntu?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd, elasticsearch, systemd-unit

I understand that `systemd` stores unit files at different locations for different versions of Linux. On RHEL, it's at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, whereas on Debian-based machines it's at `/lib/systemd/system/`.

However, on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I just installed Elasticsearch using a `.deb` file, and its `systemd` unit file was installed under `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, but `systemd` is still able to pick it up.

```
$ uname -a
Linux nucleolus 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
```

Note the path is `/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service`.

So why does a `systemd` unit file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/` still works for Ubuntu? What is the *real* unit file load path for Debian/Ubuntu systems?

Comment: Many systems have `/lib/` simply as a symlink to `/usr/lib/` to maintain compatibility with programs that use `/lib/` as the library directory. Do `ls -l /` and `ls -l /usr/` to see which `lib/` you have as a directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paths `systemd` looks up for unit files is read from `UnitPath` and can be queried with `systemctl`.

```
# systemctl --no-pager --property=UnitPath show | tr ' ' '\n'
UnitPath=/etc/systemd/system.control
/run/systemd/system.control
/run/systemd/transient
/etc/systemd/system
/run/systemd/system
/run/systemd/generator
/lib/systemd/system
/run/systemd/generator.late
```

As you can see, this does not include `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, which is the output on a Ubuntu 18.04 system. The `UnitPath` is generated during runtime and only directories that actually exist are shown here.

```
# mkdir -p /usr/lib/systemd/system
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl --no-pager --property=UnitPath show | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "/usr/lib/systemd/system"
/usr/lib/systemd/system
```

So creating the directory was enough to add `/usr/lib/systemd/system` to `UnitPath`, which was likely done by installing Elasticsearch.

---

Which directories are taken into account when constructing `UnitPath` can be queried with `pkg-config` and the variables `systemdsystemunitdir` and `systemdsystemunitpath`.

```
# pkg-config systemd --variable=systemdsystemunitdir 
/lib/systemd/system

# pkg-config systemd --variable=systemdsystemunitpath | tr ':' '\n'
/etc/systemd/system
/etc/systemd/system
/run/systemd/system
/usr/local/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system
/usr/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system
```

In [`src/core/systemd.pc.in`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/systemd.pc.in#L19-L20) the `systemdsystemunitpath` is as follows.

```
systemdsystemunitpath=${systemdsystemconfdir}:/etc/systemd/system:/run/systemd/system:/usr/local/lib/systemd/system:${systemdsystemunitdir}:/usr/lib/systemd/system:/lib/systemd/system
```